# Regex to match uppercase, lowercase and spaces in between?

Tags: regex, bash

I want to find a regex that will allow me to match uppercase, lowercase and spaces in between.

That is, below you can see a sample of what I want to collect.

```
id,name,continent
1,Louise,Latin America
2,Sasha,Asia
3,Mike,North America
```

What I am doing is that inside a while I check if the records comply with the regex. But I have found that those that have a space in between are not picked up (such as North America or Latin America). You can see my code here

```
while read line; do
  if [["$line"=~^.*,.*,[a-zA-Z ]*
```

I've also tried `[a-zA-Z\n]*` but does not work.

Any idea?

Comment: Are the "spaces" actually spaces, and not tabs or some other whitespace character? You can confirm using `hexdump`.

Comment: Whitespace is syntactically important. `[["$line"=~^.*,.*,[a-zA-Z ]*]]` is different from `[[ "$line" =~ ^.*,.*,[a-zA-Z ]* ]]` (the former isn't a regex match at all).

Comment: Welcome shiono. Your question is ambigous. Please provide some expected `grep` output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```sh
rx='^[0-9]*,[^,]*,[[:alpha:][:space:]]*$'
while read -r line; do
  if [[ "$line" =~ $rx ]]; then
  // Do something
  fi
done < file
```

*Details*:

- `^` - string start
- `[0-9]*` - zero or more digits (looks like your `ID` column can only contain digits)
- `,` - a comma
- `[^,]*`  - any zero or more chars other than `,` (`.*` is too generic and matches any text, thus it will report valid if the line contains more than three columns)
- `,` - a comma
- `[[:alpha:][:space:]]*` - zero or more letters or spaces
- `$` - end of string.

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/FJW1OM):

```sh
#!/bin/bash
s='id,name,continent
1,Louise,Latin America
2,Sasha,Asia
3,Mike,North America'
rx='^[0-9]*,[^,]*,[[:alpha:][:space:]]*$'
while read -r line; do
  if [[ "$line" =~ $rx ]]; then
      echo "$line: Valid"
  else
      echo "$line: Invalid"
  fi
done <<< "$s"
```

Output:

```
id,name,continent: Invalid
1,Louise,Latin America: Valid
2,Sasha,Asia: Valid
3,Mike,North America: Valid
```